# how to enabe halfway TLS connection in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, https, tls1.2, handshake

I have used this link [https](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_enabling_https.htm) in spring boot . Since http is state less and every time it is making full handshake when client connects, When I was searching for some performance improvement I came across this [site](https://zoompf.com/blog/2014/12/optimizing-tls-handshake/).
But I did'nt find any way to configure spring boot to enable the seesionID  .

Below are the only ssl related params

```
server.port:  
server.ssl.key-store:  
server.ssl.key-store-password:  
server.ssl.keyStoreType: 
server.ssl.keyAlias:
```